# Select 5th and any further command line parameters in bash

Tags: bash

I want to get the combine the 5th, 6th, etc parameters into one variable in bash where I don't know the number of command line parameters, eg:

```
command.sh v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 ... v9 v10
```

and have `VARIABLE=v5 v6 ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `shift` the first four parameters and use `"$*"`:

```
shift 4
var="$*"
```

If you need the first 3 parameters, save them to variables before shifting.

Answer (score 2):

Since all the arguments are stored in `$@`/`$*`, use substring expansion (which with these paraemters, is really more like array slicing):

```
VARIABLE="${*:5}"
```

(In this instance, I don't think there is a difference between `$*` and `$@`.)

Comment: Note that for many purposes it would be better to store them as an array rather than merging them into a single string -- this can be done with `arrayvar=("${@:5}")`, and then refer to the array with `"${arrayvar[@]}"`